# T-SQL query to return JSON array of strings

Tags: json, sql-server

I'm hoping to build an optimized data JSON structure that only includes data, no names.  I'll included the names in another JSON.

For example

```
[["1", "William"],["2", "Dylan"]]
```

I'm looking at "for json auto", running a query like this.

```
declare @t table(id int, name varchar(20))

insert into @t (id, name) values( 1, 'William')
insert into @t (id, name) values( 2, 'Dylan')

declare @result as varchar(max)

select id, name from @t for json auto
```

However it includes the names with every value.

```
[{"id":1,"name":"William"},{"id":2,"name":"Dylan"}]
```

Is there a way to instruct SQL Server to omit the names and just return a string array?

I'll need to update a couple hundred queries, so I'm hoping for an answer that doesn't require too much modification on a basic query.

Comment: You're likely going to want string aggregation here, not the JSON functionality.

Comment: I don't believe your "optimized" json string is valid json.

Comment: @AaronBertrand .. most likely [“id”, null]

Comment: RE: Nulls, output null, not "" so if 2 name was empty [["1","William"],["2",null]]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not support the `JSON_AGG` function or similar. You can hack it with `STRING_AGG` and `STRING_ESCAPE`.

You can either do this with a single aggregation and concatenating the row together

```sql
SELECT '[' + STRING_AGG(CONCAT(
    '["',
    id,
    '","',
    STRING_ESCAPE(name, 'json'),
    '"]'
    ), ',') + ']'
FROM @t t;
```

Or with a nested aggregation, aggregating first each row in an unpivoted subquery, then all rows together

```sql
SELECT '[' + STRING_AGG('[' + j.json + ']', ',') + ']'
FROM @t t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT STRING_AGG('"' + STRING_ESCAPE(value, 'json') + '"', ',')
    FROM (VALUES
        (CAST(id AS nvarchar(max))),
        (name)
    ) v(value)
) j(json);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c1b4b13f8d34b74e8fa9788fec46e4d0)

I've assumed columns are not nullable. Nullable columns will need special handling, I leave it as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: pay attention to NULL `values( 1, null)`

Answer (score 1):

Not all that different from Charlie's but uses `CONCAT_WS` to remove *some* of the explicit `"` characters:

```
SELECT [json] = '[' 
       + STRING_AGG('["' + CONCAT_WS('", "', id, 
         STRING_ESCAPE(COALESCE(name,''), N'JSON')) 
       + '"]', ',') + ']'
FROM @t;
```

Output (after adding a 3rd row, `values(3, NULL)`:

| json |
| --- |
| [["1", "William"],["2", "Dylan"],["3", ""]] |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9a45f6f35ec5ab79b5dec9098ee2a5ea)

If you want the literal string `null` with no quotes:

```
SELECT [json] = '[' 
       + STRING_AGG('[' 
       + CONCAT_WS(', ', CONCAT('"', id, '"'), 
           COALESCE('"' + STRING_ESCAPE(name, N'JSON') + '"', 'null'))
       + ']', ',') + ']'
FROM @t;
```

Output:

| json |
| --- |
| [["1", "William"],["2", "Dylan"],["3", null]] |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=49766a18fef077ea99994b16451aa52b)

If you don't want the `NULL` value to present a column in the JSON, just remove the `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT [json] = '[' 
       + STRING_AGG('["' + CONCAT_WS('", "', id, 
         STRING_ESCAPE(name, N'JSON')) 
       + '"]', ',') + ']'
FROM @t;
```

Output:

| json |
| --- |
| [["1", "William"],["2", "Dylan"],["3"]] |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=430262ceae6e94ac7294f123162c7796)

If you don't want that row present in the JSON at all, just filter it out:

```
FROM @t WHERE name IS NOT NULL;
```

If that column doesn't allow NULLs, state it explicitly so we don't have to guess (probably doesn't hurt to confirm `id` is unique, either):

```
declare @t table(id int UNIQUE, name varchar(20) NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks, this is really great, but how am I going to do this with 100's of queries.  I guess they will all have to be re-written, field by field?

Comment: @WilliamWalseth I wish I knew magic but if you want output that's different from the easy case (e.g. `FOR JSON AUTO`), yes? Maybe it's easier to have the consumer / application layer formulate your expected JSON output. I'm curious how you got into a state where you have 100s of queries that don't produce the output you want?

Comment: @WilliamWalseth I could envision a way to automate this _to some degree_, depending on where your queries currently live and how consistent the tables are that the queries go against, but the effort probably wouldn't be worth it (and would require lots of manual validation anyway).

Comment: Currently the queries produce XML for 100's of generated maintenance pages.  Originally, these pages were created as simple HTML forms and table lists with page refreshes between every update. 
We're updating these pages to be more responsive (all in-browser rendering), and use JSON.

Comment: @WilliamWalseth I have no way to gauge the scope but is it possible to consume the output in XML and translate _that_ to JSON, instead of reinventing all the queries individually? Maybe that should be the question if rewriting the queries isn't practical anyway...

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing currently.  We're mostly an XML shop, with some JSON.  I asked about JSON because I thought I might be missing something. Looks like XSL comes through again...

Comment: @WilliamWalseth It is an unusual requirement, to want all the rows as arrays rather than objects. I don't think it's easy even in XML. It sounds like you should rethink the way you generate these HTML pages, you should probably just use normal resultsets and format them in the application/webserver

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, you're right.  It's for a proprietary application framework, where I control both ends.  I'm hoping to keep message size small as possible, and JSON is so verbose (haha). I already have it sorted out in XSL, outputting JSON arrays on the application server as you suggest.

Comment: @WilliamWalseth Well sending a proper SQL resultset is likely to be the most efficient: the column names are sent first, then each row is sent with just the data, no metadata, so it's far more efficient than either JSON or XML

Comment: @Charlieface.  Interesting.  That's pretty much what my code is doing, but if there is standard way to do this, I'd welcome it.  Can you suggest a reference for how to render a result set in the web service response, and how to consume with JavaScript in the browser?

Comment: @WilliamWalseth Not really, it's very dependent on what framework you use. In Python have a dataframe, in .NET you have a `DataTable` or a list of custom objects. You can use that framework's tools to properly design a HTML table from that, rather than trying to bodge it with SQL Server, which is designed really to return pure resultsets

Comment: @Charlieface.  Thanks, I'm doing what you're suggesting, building data structure in C#, and the tables in the browser with JavaScript.  I'm trying to find the smallest / fastest way to get data to the browser, and if there's a better way to send the data.